# Execute custom actions before redirecting to PayPal's checkout page

Tags: paypal

I am trying to integrate Paypal's [Smart Buttons](https://www.paypal.com/buttons/smart),

And the code provided by PayPal is:

```
function initPayPalButton() {
    paypal.Buttons({
      style: {
        shape: 'rect',
        color: 'gold',
        layout: 'vertical',
        label: 'paypal',
        
      },

      createOrder: function(data, actions) {
        return actions.order.create({
          purchase_units: [{"amount":{"currency_code":"USD","value":15}}]
        });
      },

      onApprove: function(data, actions) {
        return actions.order.capture().then(function(orderData) {
          
          // Full available details
          console.log('Capture result', orderData, JSON.stringify(orderData, null, 2));

          // Show a success message within this page, e.g.
          const element = document.getElementById('paypal-button-container');
          element.innerHTML = '';
          element.innerHTML = '<h3>Thank you for your payment!</h3>';

          // Or go to another URL:  actions.redirect('thank_you.html');
          
        });
      },

      onError: function(err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    }).render('#paypal-button-container');
  }
  initPayPalButton();
```

Now, when I click the **PayPal** button, it redirects me immediately to the checkout page.

My question is, is it possible to do some actions first before it actually redirects customers to PayPal's checkout page?

Something like:

```
createOrder: function(data, actions) {
    // For example: Check if the customer is restricted for some reason
    if (isRestricted(user)) {
        // Do not redirect;
        return;
    } 

    return actions.order.create({
      purchase_units: [{"amount":{"currency_code":"USD","value":15}}]
    });

}
```

I've tried this code, but even leaving the `createOrder` function blank still seems to open a new browser tab and automatically closes. Seems like a bad UX.

Answer (score 0):

Use actions.disable() / .enabled() to ensure the buttons are disabled and re-enabled as appropriate. This is documented at [Validate user input](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/customize/validate-user-input/).

Redirect is not the technical term for what occurs for this checkout. No redirect is performed, it opens a popup window while remaining on the same page.